# Adding Salesforce1 Lightning app to Salesforce1 Navigation

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning

I have created a Lightning app in Salesforce that uses Salesforce lightning design system

```
<aura:application access="GLOBAL" extends="ltng:outApp">
  <ltng:require styles="/resource/SLDS/assets/styles/salesforce-lightning-design-system-ltng.css" />
    <div class="slds">
       <c:MySuperComponent />
    </div> 
</aura:application>
```

How can I add this app to Salesforce1 Navigation menu? Is it possible? I learned that Lightning components can be exposed but in that case, how can I include "salesforce-lightning-design-system-ltng.css" stylesheet?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

1. Use implements="force:appHostable" on component so you can use this component for salesforce1.
2. Add lightning tab for APP.
3. From Setup, enter Navigation in the Quick Find box, then select Salesforce1 Navigation.
   Select the custom tab you just created and click Add.